# Parse JSON Array in php and add values to php array

Tags: php, json

I have a json object of this type:

```
{
    "order": {
        "Food": "[Test 1, Test 2, Test 0, Test 3, Test 1, Test 3, Test 11, Test 7, Test 9, Test 8, Test 2]",
        "Quantity": "[2, 3, 6, 2, 1, 7, 10, 2, 0, 0, 1]"
    },
    "tag": "neworder"
}
```

I have used json_decode but i would like to take the values inside Food and Quantity and store them inside a php array, i ve tried many approaches but really with no luck.
Could someone point to the right way to do it, or is something wrong with my json message??

Comment: Can you show some of the code you used?

Comment: It seems that the "Food" and "Quality" values are themselves json strings

Comment: foreach($parsedJSON->order->Food as $mydata)

    {
         $response["test2"] = $mydata;
    }

Comment: And also precise what you exactly want to put in each element of the array.

Comment: yes thats correct, Explosion Pills

Comment: I want to put the values "Test 1, Test 2, etc." and "2,3,6,etc."

Comment: you have json encoded string as properties of a javascript object encoded with json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[PHP json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)'s 2nd argument set to true will return associative arrays instead of objects.

Additionaly, your JSON is valid but your Food entry resolves to a string when using json_decode. In order to have the array you want this code snippet will work:

```
<?php
$json  = '{"order":{"Food":"[Test 1, Test 2, Test 0, Test 3, Test 1, Test 3, Test 11, Test 7, Test 9, Test 8, Test 2]","Quantity":[2,3,6,2,1,7,10,2,0,0,1]},"tag":"neworder"}';
$array = json_decode($json, true);

// Fix Food array entry
$array['order']['Food'] = explode(', ', trim($array['order']['Food'], '[]'));

print_r($array);
```

This way you'll get a PHP array to manipulate at will:

```
Array
(
    [order] => Array
        (
            [Food] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Test 1
                    [1] => Test 2
                    [2] => Test 0
                    [3] => Test 3
                    [4] => Test 1
                    [5] => Test 3
                    [6] => Test 11
                    [7] => Test 7
                    [8] => Test 9
                    [9] => Test 8
                    [10] => Test 2
                )

            [Quantity] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2
                    [1] => 3
                    [2] => 6
                    [3] => 2
                    [4] => 1
                    [5] => 7
                    [6] => 10
                    [7] => 2
                    [8] => 0
                    [9] => 0
                    [10] => 1
                )
        )
    [tag] => neworder
)
```

Comment: thnx very much, worked great, although i think i must organise my JSON in a different way so that it is easier to handle

Answer (score 0):

If this:

```
{
    "order": {
        "Food": "[Test 1, Test 2, Test 0, Test 3, Test 1, Test 3, Test 11, Test 7, Test 9, Test 8, Test 2]",
        "Quantity": "[2, 3, 6, 2, 1, 7, 10, 2, 0, 0, 1]"
    },
    "tag": "neworder"
}
```

is truely the json that you are using then you are going to have to do a little work to get what you want.

```
$obj = json_decode($json);
// the food and quantity properties are string not json.
$foods = explode("," trim($obj->order->Food;, "[]"));
$foods = array_map("trim", $foods); // get rid of the extra spaces
$quantitys = json_decode($obj->order->Quantity);
```

For this to have been valid json it would have to be authored like

```
{
    "order": {
        "Food": ["Test 1", "Test 2", "Test 0", "Test 3", "Test 1", "Test 3", "Test 11", "Test 7", "Test 9", "Test 8", "Test 2"],
        "Quantity": [2, 3, 6, 2, 1, 7, 10, 2, 0, 0, 1]
    },
    "tag": "neworder"
}
```